# Elasticsearch create index and post

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to perform actions in ES, so far I believe that I was able established connection correctly using Jest(http request) and now I am trying to create a new topic and post some information so it will be visible throw the elasticsearch head plugin, I run my code I dont receive any Exception but nothing happens as well,

```
   public class ElasticSearch {

  private String ES_HOST = "localhost";
  private String ES_PORT = "9200";
  private static JestClient jestClient = null;

  public JestClient getElasticSearchClient() {
    return jestClient;
  }

  public void connectToElasticSearch() {

    try {
      JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
      factory.setHttpClientConfig(
              new HttpClientConfig.Builder("http://" + ES_HOST + ":" + ES_PORT)
                      .multiThreaded(true)
                      //            //Per default this implementation will create no more than 2 concurrent
                      // connections per given route
                      //            .defaultMaxTotalConnectionPerRoute(<YOUR_DESIRED_LEVEL_OF_CONCURRENCY_PER_ROUTE>)
                      //            // and no more 20 connections in total
                      //            .maxTotalConnection(<YOUR_DESIRED_LEVEL_OF_CONCURRENCY_TOTAL>)
                      .build());
      jestClient = factory.getObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void createIndex(String indexName, String indexType) throws IOException {
    // jestClient.execute(new CreateIndex.Builder(indexName).build());
    PutMapping putMapping = new PutMapping.Builder(
            indexName,
            indexType,
            "{ \"my_type\" : { \"properties\" : { \"message\" : {\"type\" : \"string\", \"store\" : \"yes\"} } } }"
    ).build();
    jestClient.execute(putMapping);

  }

  public void postInES() throws IOException {
    String source = jsonBuilder()
            .startObject()
            .field("user", "kimchy")
            .field("postDate", "date")
            .field("message", "trying out Elastic Search")
            .endObject().string();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ElasticSearch es = new ElasticSearch();
    es.connectToElasticSearch();
    es.getElasticSearchClient();
    es.createIndex("ES TEST", "TEST");
    es.postInES();

  }
```

I am using:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.searchbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>jest</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>6.2.4</version>
</dependency>`enter code here`
```

I will appreciate your help

thanks

Comment: You can try two options, according to https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/main/java/io/searchbox/client/http/JestHttpClient.java#L66 *execute* command has a response object, you can check this response object or check the logs for elastic search itself. If there is something wrong one of these two will probably give you a hint.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I found few problems in my code above and I was able to fix it, first when using java the port has to be 9300 and not 9200, I actually changed my entire code and decided to use TransportClient instead of JestClient which helped me. in case anyone else needs or had a similar problem I will share my code here hope it will help others

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.cluster.health.ClusterHealthResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.CreateIndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.exists.indices.IndicesExistsResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.action.support.WriteRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.common.unit.TimeValue;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentFactory;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.BulkByScrollResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.DeleteByQueryAction;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.FieldSortBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.search.sort.SortOrder;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * @author YoavT @Date 6/26/2018 @Time 9:20 AM
 */
public class ElasticSearch{

  private String ES_HOST = "localhost";
  private int ES_PORT = 9300;
  private TransportClient client = null;


  protected boolean connectToElasticSearch(String clusterName) {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
      Settings settings =
              Settings.builder()
                      .put("cluster.name", clusterName)
                      .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true)
                      .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                      .build();

      // create connection
      client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);
      client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ES_HOST), ES_PORT));

      System.out.println(
              "Connection " + clusterName + "@" + ES_HOST + ":" + ES_PORT + " established!");
      flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      flag = false;
    }
    return flag;
  }

  /**
   * Check the health status of the cluster
   */
  public boolean isClusterHealthy(String clusterName) {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    final ClusterHealthResponse response =
            client
                    .admin()
                    .cluster()
                    .prepareHealth()
                    .setWaitForGreenStatus()
                    .setTimeout(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(2))
                    .execute()
                    .actionGet();

    if (response.isTimedOut()) {
      System.out.println("The cluster is unhealthy: " + response.getStatus());
      return false;
    }

    System.out.println("The cluster is healthy: " + response.getStatus());
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * Previous step is (check if cluster is healthy) The cluster is ready now and we can start with
   * creating an index. Before that, we check that the same index was not created previously.
   */
  public boolean isIndexRegistered(String indexName, String clusterName) {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    // check if index already exists
    final IndicesExistsResponse ieResponse =
            client.admin().indices().prepareExists(indexName).get(TimeValue.timeValueSeconds(1));

    // index not there
    if (!ieResponse.isExists()) {
      return false;
    }

    System.out.println("Index already created!");
    return true;
  }

  /**
   * If the index does not exist already, we create the index. *
   */
  public boolean createIndex(String indexName, String numberOfShards, String numberOfReplicas, String clusterName) {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    try {
      CreateIndexResponse createIndexResponse =
              client
                      .admin()
                      .indices()
                      .prepareCreate(indexName.toLowerCase())
                      .setSettings(
                              Settings.builder()
                                      .put("index.number_of_shards", numberOfShards)
                                      .put("index.number_of_replicas", numberOfReplicas))
                      .get();

      if (createIndexResponse.isAcknowledged()) {
        System.out.println(
                "Created Index with "
                        + numberOfShards
                        + " Shard(s) and "
                        + numberOfReplicas
                        + " Replica(s)!");
        return true;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ElasticSearch elasticSearch = new ElasticSearch();
    elasticSearch.connectToElasticSearch("elasticsearch");
    boolean isHealthy = elasticSearch.isClusterHealthy("elasticsearch");
    System.out.println("is cluster healthy= " + isHealthy);
    boolean isIndexExsist = elasticSearch.isIndexRegistered("Test", "elasticsearch");
    System.out.println("is index exsist = " + isIndexExsist);
    boolean createIndex = elasticSearch.createIndex("TestIndex", "3", "1", "elasticsearch");
    System.out.println("Is index created = " + createIndex);
    boolean bulkInsert = elasticSearch.bulkInsert("TestIndex", "Json", "elasticsearch");
    System.out.println("Bulk insert = " + bulkInsert);
    long deleteBulk = elasticSearch.deleteBulk("TestIndex", "name", "Mark Twain", "elasticsearch");
    System.out.println("Delete bulk = " + deleteBulk);
  }

  /**
   * We basically want to index a JSON array consisting of objects with the properties name and age. We use a bulk insert to insert all the data at once.
   * In our tests it happened that the cluster health status was not ready when we tried to run a search/delete query directly after the insert. Consequently,
   * we added the setRefreshPolicy( RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE ) method to signalize the server to refresh the index after the specified request.
   * The data can now be queried directly after.
   *
   * @param indexName
   * @param indexType
   * @return
   * @throws IOException
   */

  public boolean bulkInsert(String indexName, String indexType, String clusterName) throws IOException {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    boolean flag = true;
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();
    // for (int i = 0; i < listOfParametersForInsertion.length; i++) {

    bulkRequest
            .setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE)
            .add(
                    client
                            .prepareIndex(indexName, indexType, null)
                            .setSource(
                                    XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                                            .startObject()
                                            .field("name", "Mark Twain")
                                            .field("age", 75)
                                            .endObject()));
    // }
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.get();
    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
      // process failures by iterating through each bulk response item
      System.out.println("Bulk insert failed!");
      flag = false;
    }

    return flag;
  }

  /**
   * After successfully querying data, we try to delete documents using a key-value pair to get
   * deeper into the Elasticsearch behavior.
   */
  public long deleteBulk(String indexName, String key, String value, String clusterName) {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    BulkByScrollResponse response =
            DeleteByQueryAction.INSTANCE
                    .newRequestBuilder(client)
                    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchQuery(key, value))
                    .source(indexName)
                    .refresh(true)
                    .get();

    System.out.println("Deleted " + response.getDeleted() + " element(s)!");

    return response.getDeleted();
  }

  /**
   * To query the data, we use a SearchResponse in combination with a scroll. A scroll is basically
   * the Elasticsearch counterpart to a cursor in a traditional SQL database. Using that sort of
   * query is quite an overkill for our example and just for demonstration purposes. It is rather
   * used to query large amounts of data (not like five documents in our case) and not intended for
   * real-time user requests.
   *
   * @param indexName
   * @param from
   * @param to
   */
  public void queryResultsWithFilter(String indexName, int from, int to, String clusterName, String filterField) {
    connectToElasticSearch(clusterName);
    SearchResponse scrollResp =
            client
                    .prepareSearch(indexName)
                    // sort order
                    .addSort(FieldSortBuilder.DOC_FIELD_NAME, SortOrder.ASC)
                    // keep results for 60 seconds
                    .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                    // filter for age
                    .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(filterField).from(from).to(to))
                    // maximum of 100 hits will be returned for each scroll
                    .setSize(100)
                    .get();

    // scroll until no hits are returned
    do {
      int count = 1;
      for (SearchHit hit : scrollResp.getHits().getHits()) {
        Map<String, Object> res = hit.getSourceAsMap();

        // print results
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : res.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println("[" + count + "] " + entry.getKey() + " --> " + entry.getValue());
        }
        count++;
      }

      scrollResp =
              client
                      .prepareSearchScroll(scrollResp.getScrollId())
                      .setScroll(new TimeValue(60000))
                      .execute()
                      .actionGet();
      // zero hits mark the end of the scroll and the while loop.
    } while (scrollResp.getHits().getHits().length != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, a concise package of everything I needed. Thank you!